# Delphi. Не работает goto

Tags: delphi, pascal, goto

Входные значения: -2 2 0.5 0
Когда числа не удовлетворяют область допустимых значений нужно сделать соответсвующий вывод и перескочить вывод когда числа совпадают с ОДЗ. Но получается дублирование строк.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  math;
label skip;
var
  xn, xk, dx, w, x, a : real;
begin
  try
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;

  write('Enter xn, xk, dx, a: ');
  readln(xn,xk,dx,a);
  writeln('X=[',xn:3:1, ', ',xk:3:1,'] dx=',dx:4:2,' a=',a:2:1);
  writeln;
  x:=xn;
  while x<=xk do
    begin
      if x>a then
      w:=x*x-(1/4)*-power(abs((power(a,3)-power(x,3))), (1/3))
      else if x=a then
      w:=log10((1/3)*a*a+(2/5))+exp(a+x)
      else
        begin
          if ((a*a-x*x)<=0) or (a*x/3=3.14/2) or (a*x/3=3.14*3/2) then
          writeln('x=', x:4:2, ' W=.. a- слишком маленькое (ОДЗ)')
          else
              w:=power(tan((a*x)/3),2)-(1/3)*sqrt(a*a-x*x);
              writeln('x=', x:4:2, ' W=', w:4:2);//вывод когда ОДЗ - не ок
              x:=x+dx;
              goto skip; //перепрыгнуть второй вывод
        end;
      writeln('x=', x:5:2, ' W=', w:4:2);//вывод когда ОДЗ - ок
      x:=x+dx;
      skip:  //сюда прыгаем
    end;
  readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Не экономьте на `begin`/`end`.

   ```
   if ((a*a-x*x)<=0) or (a*x/3=3.14/2) or (a*x/3=3.14*3/2) then
   begin 
     writeln('x=', x:4:2, ' W=.. a- слишком маленькое (ОДЗ)');
   end
   else
   begin
     w:=power(tan((a*x)/3),2)-(1/3)*sqrt(a*a-x*x);
     writeln('x=', x:4:2, ' W=', w:4:2);//вывод когда ОДЗ - не ок
     x:=x+dx;
     goto skip; //перепрыгнуть второй вывод
   end;
   ```
2. Вместо `goto skip;` используйте `continue;`.